# Jsoup node hash code collision when traversing DOM tree

Tags: java, html, dom, hash, jsoup

I'm using java jsoup to build HTML DOM trees, in which `Node.hashCode()` is used. But I find there are a lot of hash code collisions when traversing the DOM tree, using the following code:

```
doc.traverse(new NodeVisitor(){

    @Override
    public void head(Node node, int depth) {

        System.out.println("node hash: "+ node.hashCode());

        /* some other operations */
    }

    @Override
    public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /* some codes */
    }
}
```

So when this is run, I see many identical hash codes even in the first several outputs.

The hash codes are pretty large and I don't expect such weird behavior. I used jsoup-1.8.1.
 Any input will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Out of interest, is the content of the nodes identical? Would be interesting if 1) the hash is created from the content or 2) it identifies duplication to reduce memory footprint.

Comment: The html pages I used are from Amazon (I want to analyze the fields in their product pages). I think each one is unique in terms of content. Even if there're nodes with identical contents, it cannot be that many.

Comment: Could you provide some html sample that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: @alkis , I can reproduce it, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note:** This bug has been fixed in jSoup 1.8.2, so my answer is no longer relevant.

It might to be a bug in jSoup source. From the [source](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.java):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
   int result = parentNode != null ? parentNode.hashCode() : 0;
   // not children, or will block stack as they go back up to parent)
   result = 31 * result + (attributes != null ? attributes.hashCode() : 0);
   return result;
}
```

I'm not a Java expert, but this looks like it could return the same value for different Nodes, if they have the same attributes. (And the same parent, thanks @alkis for the comment)

---

**Edit:** I can reproduce this. Using the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="blah">TODO: write content</div>
        <div style="blah">Nothing here</div>
        <p style="test">Empty</p>
        <p style="nothing">Empty</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the following code:

```
String html = //HTML posted above

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements elements = doc.select("[style]");
for (Element e : elements) {
   System.out.println(e.hashCode());
}
```

It gives:

```
-148184373
-148184373
-1050420242
2013043377
```

It seems to ignore the content text entirely while calculating the hash, and only the attributes are important.

---

You should probably implement your own workaround.

---

Bug reported [here](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/537).

Comment: Clearly these two `<div style="blah">TODO: write content</div><div style="blah">Nothing here</div>` have the same hash. They have the same attribute (`style="blah"`) and the same parent. Yes, this must be a bug. You should file it. Good find. Kudos!

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I've fixed this. It will be in jsoup 1.8.2